# Find a name that is not used in another table

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-6

In my **Role.php** I have the following.

```php
class Role extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

I tried a query like this:

```
$leaders = Role::where('name','leader')->with('users')->first();
```

I got two names by querying this:

```
1->Tanvir AHmed
2->Nayeem
```

And, I have another table named `teams` and it has a column named `leader_name` and data like the following:

```
teams.leader_name
Tanvir AHmed
```

Now I want to fetch the names which are not contained in the teams' table. Like, in this case, Tanvir is present and Nayeem is not. How can I fetch this name(Nayeem)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in two steps:

```php
// First step: retrieve all team_leaders distinct values
$team_leader_names = Teams::groupBy('team_leaders')->get()->pluck('name');

// Second step: search users by name
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($query){
               $query->where('name', '=', 'leader');
           })->whereNotIn('name', team_leader_names)->get();
```

Anwyay, it would be much simpler if the `teams` table had a `leader_id` foreign key. And there are many reasons:

1. What if there are two users with `leader role` and same name, but only one is a `team leader`? The query above will exclude both.
2. What if someone changes it's name due to, for example, a typing error? You should change also the `leader_name` column and this makes your code more complex.
3. Foreign keys are more suitable anyway for these operations.

With a foreign key, your query will become:

```php
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($query){
               $query->where('name', '=', 'leader');
           })->whereDoesntHave('leadership')->get();
```

and, for example, `leadership` is defined as relation in you `User` model as follow:

```php
public class User {

    // [...]

    public function leadership() {
        return $this->hasMany('teams', 'leader_id');
    }

}
```